# Is "a very good read" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct to describe a book or article as *a very good read*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is correct. Here *[read](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/read_2)* is used as a noun referring to the thing that is being read. Note that the noun can also mean the act of reading something. The two senses are similar enough that sometimes they are [not distinguished](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/read_4).

Comment: Or, rather, by extension and when preceded by 'good', something for reading.

Comment: "Read" here does not mean the act, but the thing that is read, such as a book or an article. "Read" can mean what you say, but not in this context. See the examples in dictionary.com for a comparison of the two meanings.

Comment: and for multiple articles or books, can we say 'nice reads' or should it be 'nice read'?

Answer (score 2):

The process by which a word that has previously functioned exclusively as verb but has been refactored as a noun in modern usage is called  nominalization. Examples are:

- a hard sell
- a must have
- a new install
- an unexpected invite

I could invent new examples:

- My new suitcase is a heavy carry.
- His phone number is an easy remember.

Are constructions are grammtically correct? Well, that's a very difficult ask.

Here is a good article on the topic: [Mighty Morphin' Parts of Speech](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/ll/1412/).